# ¿Por que no puedo agregar registros en una columna Identity?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Tengo el siguiente error en SQL Server:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 759
> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'NumCliente', table 'CRG_PRUEBAS.dbo.CLIENTE'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Mi tabla CLIENTE tiene como primary key un INT IDENTITY(1,1)

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE
(NumCliente INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 Nombre1 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 Nombre2 VARCHAR(30) NULL,
 Apellido1 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 Apellido2 VARCHAR(30) NULL,
 Genero VARCHAR(9) NULL,
 CentrodeTrabajo Varchar(100) NULL,
 Telefono VARCHAR(20) NULL,
 Correo VARCHAR(50) NULL)
GO
```

Ya he agregado muchos registros a la tabla (Aunque mi identity se volvio loco y salto del 100 al 1000 (por ejemplo))... El caso que de un tiempo para aca me sale ese error y no me deja agregar registros...

Ejemplo de como agrego nuevos cliente:

```
INSERT INTO CLIENTE (Nombre1,
                     Nombre2,
                     Apellido1,
                     Apellido2,
                     Genero,
                     CentrodeTrabajo,
                     Telefono,
                     Correo)
           VALUES( 
                    'Nombre1',
                    'Nombre2',
                    'Apellido1',
                    'Apellido2',
                    'Masculino',
                    'PEMEX',
                    '(999)999-9999',
                    'A@A')
GO
```

Espero su pronta ayuda, Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Anexo captura igual cuando mi identity dio un salto muy loco...
[image: Despues de 2000 me salgo a 3000 y despues a 4000 y despues a 7000 y ahorita ya anda en 8000...pero no puedo agregar registros...]

Comment: Tal vez esté un poco corto de vista, pero no veo ningún error en el `Insert`. Revisa nuevamente la definición de la Tabla en SSMS haciéndole click derecho y genera el script en una nueva ventana o archivo. Asegúrate que no se ha cambiado/eliminado la definición de la columna `NumCliente`

Comment: Si bro, hace unas semanas funcionaba perfectamente, ahora me manda ese error... y la tabla no ha sido modificada... ya genere el script y esta de la misma manera, tengo ese problema con todas mis tablas que tienen IDENTITY.

Comment: Lo del salto suele pasar cuando uno usa una secuencia, esta tiene un caché mayor a 1 y por algún motivoel motor descarta el caché y carga nuevos valores. Podría uno suponer que la columna identity usa algo así internamente y esa puede ser la causa. Históricamente eso (me) ha pasado con MS SQL y "he perdido" rangos incluso mayores en las secuencias

Comment: En esa cuestion, el problema de que haga esos saltos es que ahorita ya va en el 8000... cuando apenas y tengo agregados a 1500 clientes... @Alfabravo

Comment: Lo bueno: Eso funcionalmente no debería afectarte, porque además obedece a un comportamiento interno de la BD. Por cierto, qué versión de MSSQL estás usando?

Comment: @Alfabravo SQL Server Management Studio 18. con un proyecto de Visual Studio y C#. del problema principal que tengo...alguna idea? :(

Comment: Ese es el cliente con el que te conectas a la BD. CUál es la versión de MS Sql Server?

Comment: La version es 14.0.2027 si a eso te refieres... me agarras frió ante ese conocimiento.

Comment: Según la documentación, significa que es versión 2017 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4047329/sql-server-2017-build-versions  Este dato siempre debes tenerlo presente en cualquier motor porque las caracteríßticas, los bugs y los workarounds varían de versión en versión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pareciera que la propiedad de identity no está funcionando.

Si las tablas están definidas correctamente (y hay que revisar que se haya revisado en la base de datos correcta de la instancia correcta) entonces debe ser un bug. La versión que tienes es previa al primer CU. Lo recomendable es que instales el último CU que puedes encontrar en [esta página](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56128). También puedes revisar tu versión en [esta página](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4047329/sql-server-2017-build-versions).

Si eso aún no soluciona tu problema, lo ideal es que contactes a la gente de Microsoft para indicarles el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya estoy actualizando la version.

Comment: Me recuerda un bug que me puso a obligar a los clientes a usar mssql 2016 cu6 o superior... a veces uno se pregunta por qué liberan versiones con fallas básicas

Comment: Hola, pasa algo raro... ¿sera que se haya dañado mis tablas IDENTITY? cree 2 tablas como ejemplo con identity en la primary key...aparte, cree otra tabla con los mismos datos de la tabla cliente y se agrega bien!!... pero en la tabla que ya esta creada de cliente y tiene registros marca el error...

Answer (score 1):

Sobre los saltos en el campo IDENTITY, tal cual lo indicaba en los comentarios, [se ha identificado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14146237/236345) que se debe a una [*optimización*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) del motor que hace que conserve un cache de números y por diferentes motivos puede descartarlo por completo y arrancar en el número inmediatamente siguiente al mayor de ese caché descartado. El caché es de 1000 para int, 10000 para bigint.

¿Cuándo se van a dar estos saltos? Cuando reinicien el servidor. ¿Como evitarlos? Configurando la base de datos, la secuencia con parámetros para evitar que cree el caché (que igual le va a pegar al performance, que no es lo mismo ir y consultar el valor al disco que tenerlo en memoria listo para usar).

1. Se puede evitar usar IDENTITY y usar un SEQUENCE con un valor de cache menor (10? 50? depende de tu aplicación), poniendo en el DEFAULT del campo de la tabla, el NEXT VALUE FOR la nueva secuencia.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE clienteNumeroSeq AS BIGINT START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 100;
...
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE
(
  NumCliente INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_numcliente_id DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR clienteNumeroSeq,
...
```

2. Se puede ejecutar `ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION  SET IDENTITY_CACHE = OFF` para deshabilitar el cacheo de campos IDENTITY para toda la base de datos (a mí no me gustan estas opciones globales pero pues... es una opción).

Igual, por diseño, ni las secuencias ni los campos IDENTITY garantizan que no haya saltos (como te decía, tu funcionalidad no debe depender de que este campo sea secuencial sin saltos, como en un número de factura o similar). Para eso debe usarse otra implementación que sí garantice ese comportamiento.

Sobre la inserción que habla de un campo IDENTITY nulo, no me queda más que sumarme a la respuesta de @LuisCazares pues no hay ni bugs ni documentación registrada que mencione incidentes similares. Lo más sano es, pues, instalar el Cumulative Update más reciente y probar de nuevo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder. Me queda totalmente entendido el funcionamiento del IDENTITY y que no pasa nada que incremente feo... aunque como programador me molesta un poco es parte. Por ultimo, nuevamente agradezco tu respuesta pero el problema en si de la pregunta es el mensaje de error y que no puedo agregar datos a las tablas IDENTITY por ese error que me sale.